# Add Item Form Easy Tabs

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, infopath, form, list-form

I don't know where to begin.

Problem.  I have a form that has numerous fields.  There are so many fields it's confusing.

Objective: I was thinking I could added easy tabs on the form that could separate the fields by topic.  But, I do not know where to start.

Question:  Do you think adding easy tabs on the form is a good suggestion?  Or, do you think there is a better way develop a user friendly form?  Can this be done just in SharePoint/SharePoint Designer?  Do I need to use InfoPath?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So you can use [Tabs for SharePoint forms](http://www.nothingbutsharepoint.com/2011/01/18/tabs-for-sharepoint-forms-aspx/). You will get similar view like following

[image]

Very easy to use! It's just the use of Content Editor Web Part.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/Javascript/TabsForSharePointForms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
var tabConstructor = {tabs:[{name:'First Tab',fields:['Title','MyPeoplePicker','MyRichText'],mouseOver:'This is the first tab',tabStyle:''},
                            {name:'Second Tab',fields:['MyDateTime','MyMultiLookup'],mouseOver:'This is the second tab',tabStyle:''},
                            {name:'Third Tab',fields:['MySingleLookup','MyTextField'],mouseOver:'This is the third tab',tabStyle:''},
                            {name:'Attachments',fields:['attachments'],mouseOver:'',tabStyle:''}],
                      settings:{
                        viewAllFields:{show:true,name:'All fields',mouseOver:'This tab shows all fields',tabStyle:''},
                        orphanFields:{show:true,name:'...',mouseOver:'All orphan fields',tabStyle:''},
                        breakTabRowAt:null,
                        hoverTabColor:'#FFF68F',
                        selectedTabColor:'#B9D3EE'}};

init_buildTabbedForm(tabConstructor,1);
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, Atish Dipongkor   So, I would add every web part to every view within the custom list library?  The link provided a way to so in SP07 and SP10 not SP13.  Just wanted to know if I follow the same steps for SP10.  Thanks

Comment: It also works with sp13. I have added with many sp13 lists!

Answer (score 1):

Right click on each of the fields and on the top ribbon under "Properties" and "NAME" you can write what the field is.

Note: You can only write "CandidateName" vs "Candidate Name" with a space. Now on the right side where you normally see your fields, it will display the name you entered and you will be aware of what each one is.

***** This same instance for Candidate Name, before the my field is used by the user right before the box I simply wrote Candidate Name so they know what belongs there.

*****Another solution could be to make an extra row and put an extra field in there with the name, and then hide it for your view only.

Comment: Thanks VKay.  Can you explain this further?  How would this give me tabs on the New Item page?